# How to delete specific items from a VBA collection?

Tags: excel, vba, loops, collections

I've been trying to create a macro that does this:

Example worksheet:

[image: Example worksheet]

1.Get column 'A','B' and 'C' into separate collections.

2.Check collection 'A' items if they contain "-".

3. If item contains "-" delete the item with same index in all 3 collections.
4. Then unload collection 'A' into column 'D' and loop format the cells based on if the "B" column and "C" column collection same index items value ="" or not ="".

Initial code:

1. Creating collection:

```
    Function ReadRangeRowsToCollection(r As Range) As Collection

        Dim iRow As Long
        Dim iCol As Long
        Dim rangeArr As Variant
        Dim rowArr As Variant
        Dim c As Collection
    
        rangeArr = r.Value
        Set c = New Collection
        For iRow = 1 To r.Rows.Count
            ReDim rowArr(1 To r.Columns.Count)
            For iCol = 1 To r.Columns.Count
                rowArr(iCol) = rangeArr(iRow, iCol)
            Next iCol
            c.Add rowArr, CStr(iRow)
        Next iRow
    
        Set ReadRangeRowsToCollection = c
    End Function
```

2. Checking collections:

```
     Dim atid As Collection
       Dim uzdar As Collection
       Dim inv As Collection
        Set inv = ReadRangeRowsToCollection(ws1.Range("A1", ws1.Cells(lRow, "A")))
        Set atid = ReadRangeRowsToCollection(ws1.Range("B1", ws1.Cells(lRow, "B")))
        Set uzdar = ReadRangeRowsToCollection(ws1.Range("C1", ws1.Cells(lRow, "C")))
            Dim i As Integer
            i = inv.Count
            For x = i To 1 Step -1
                 If InStr(CStr(inv.item(x)), "-") > 0 Then
                 inv.Remove x
                 End If
            Next x
```

Encountered problems:

If i use `For Each` item in collection loop, i don't know how to properly loop when deleted the collection items shift to top of the collection and `For each` doesn't support looping from the bottom.
If i use `For x= variable to 1 Step-1` i can't properly get the value of the collection item and check if it contains "-"
I tried to change my "Creating collection" function to this:

```
    Set c = New Collection
        For iRow = 1 To r.Rows.Count
            ReDim rowArr(1 To r.Columns.Count)
            For iCol = 1 To r.Columns.Count
                If Not InStr(rangeArr(iRow, iCol), "-") > 0 Then
                rowArr(iCol) = rangeArr(iRow, iCol)
                Else
                GoTo praleist
                End If
            Next iCol
            c.Add rowArr, CStr(iRow)
    praleist:
        Next iRow
```

But then, how to delete the unwanted items from other collections ?

As an idea there is dumping the cut "A" column collection then loop "Find" the cells and format based on offset cells. Though that's not an ideal option as the original worksheet has 243 worksheets with 100-2000 rows.

Thank you for your help and tips.

A,B,C columns are before

E,F,G columns are desired result

[image]

Comment: Please add a screenshot of your desired output

Comment: It seems that, instead of Collections, your first three steps could be handled with a simple filter (select all rows that do NOT contain a hyphen).  And I don't really understand your fourth step -- hence a picture of your output, given your posted input, might be useful.

Comment: Added a desired output @RonRosenfeld

Comment: Why do you need collections at all?  Examining your desired result, as I wrote, you can clearly obtain that with a simple filter and a copy/paste operation. You can do this on the worksheet, with VBA or in Power Query.

Comment: The main goal is to loop through about 200 sheets and 100-2000 rows and return the desired output in a single sheet. I thought using collections would be the fastest way.

Comment: That being the case, you can do this with a single collection or dictionary item.  Also use VBA arrays to speed up processing. I will post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*The main goal is to loop through about 200 sheets and 100-2000 rows and return the desired output in a single sheet. I thought using collections would be the fastest way.*

For speed purposes, I would try the following:

- Check each worksheet to ensure data is valid
- Read the entire data range into a VBA array for faster processing

  - This will be five to ten times faster than reading each line from the worksheet
- Use a Single collection object storing each row as an item
- Only store the rows where the first column does not have a hyphen
- *Note that I used the `WorksheetFunction.Index` method to store an entire array "row" at once. I've not tested the speed of this vs creating an array by looping through the three elements, but if speed is an issue, that would be a thought*

1. *I manually created the Summary worksheet before running the macro*
2. *I created a second worksheet similar to the first, just for testing*
3. *On my sheets, the data started at row 2*

```
Option Explicit
Sub removeIt()
    Dim WS As Worksheet
    Dim myCol As Collection
    Dim vSrc As Variant, rSrc As Range, rRes As Range
    Dim I As Long, J As Long
    Dim vRes As Variant

Set myCol = New Collection
For Each WS In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

    'does it have the correct data
    If Not WS.Name = "Summary" And Left(WS.Cells(2, 1), 5) = "CONF/" Then
        With WS
            vSrc = Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Resize(columnsize:=3)
        End With
        
        'just add the rows with no hyphen
        For I = 1 To UBound(vSrc, 1)
            If InStr(vSrc(I, 1), "-") = 0 Then
                myCol.Add WorksheetFunction.Index(vSrc, I)
            End If
        Next I
    End If
Next WS

'create a results array
ReDim vRes(1 To myCol.Count, 1 To 3)
For I = 1 To myCol.Count
    For J = 1 To 3
        vRes(I, J) = myCol(I)(J)
    Next J
Next I
                
'write the results array and format on summary worksheet
Set WS = Worksheets("Summary")
With WS
    Set rRes = Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(UBound(vRes, 1), 3))
    With rRes
        .EntireColumn.Clear
        .Value = vRes
        Union(.Columns(2), .Columns(3)).NumberFormat = "yyyy.mm.dd"
        .EntireColumn.AutoFit
        .Style = "Output" 'style name is language dependent
    End With
End With
        
End Sub
```

**Data1**
[image]

**Data2**
[image]

**Results**
[image]

Comment: Wow this works great. What if the columns would be further apart? Like first column is "B", second one is "H" and the third one is "AA"? How to adapt to that?

Comment: @baxius My solution is for your problem as presented. If you change the data layout to what you describe, what to do would depend on what you wanted to happen to the intervening columns, but the same general principles would apply.  You could first adjust `vSrc` to read in the entire `B2:AAn`; and then store either the entire row as we did; or an array consisting of columns 1, 7 and 25.  If the latter, you'd write the columns back to the worksheet one column at a time.

Comment: @baxius  If you were doing nothing with the intervening columns, you could also read the three columns into three separate arrays; for each array create a second array consisting of the three elements at the same index in the "key" array that does not have hyphens; and store that array in your collection.  Then create three separate vba arrays from the collection to write back to the worksheet.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to create collections initially without "-":

```
Function GetCollections() 'returns array of Collection
    Dim retval(1 To 3)
    For i = 1 To 3
        Set retval(i) = New Collection
    Next
    
    Set Rng = Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Columns(1).Cells ' replace with your own range with data
    For Each cl In Rng
        If Not cl.Value Like "*-*" Then
            For i = 1 To 3
                ' if the first column A contains no "-" then iterate over collections and add the values from the near cells with offset()
                retval(i).Add cl.Offset(, i - 1).Value, CStr(cl.Row)
            Next
        End If
    Next
    GetCollections = retval
End Function

Sub Usage()
    Dim a As Collection, b  As Collection, c  As Collection, buf
    buf = GetCollections
    Set a = buf(1)
    Set b = buf(2)
    Set c = buf(3)
    
    ' do whatever you want
End Sub
```